# How to attach CodenameOne sources to my project?

Tags: codenameone

I wanted to dive into CN1 soures. I've followed [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html) and [this tutorial](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/use-the-source.html) with git. However in NetBeans when I ctrl-click on a CN1 object it shows "Showing generated source file. No sources are attached to class' JAR file.". If I attach the sources I've just downloaded ie "CodenameOne/CodenameOne/src" the sources are still unfound!

I tried to clean and build the project but errors appeared :

```
Building jar: /home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/CodenameOne/dist/CodenameOne.jar
CodenameOne.jar:
JavaSE.init:
JavaSE.deps-jar:
Created dir: /home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/build
Updating property file: /home/pathTo/myProject/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir:     /home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/build/classes
Created dir: /home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/build/empty
Created dir: /home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 21 source files to /home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/build/classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
/home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/JavaSEPort.java:115: error: package com.jhlabs.image does not exist
import com.jhlabs.image.GaussianFilter;
/home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/JavaSEPort.java:8757: error: cannot find symbol
    GaussianFilter gf = new GaussianFilter(radius);
symbol:   class GaussianFilter
location: class JavaSEPort
    /home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/JavaSEPort.java:8757: error: cannot find symbol
    GaussianFilter gf = new GaussianFilter(radius);
symbol:   class GaussianFilter    location: class JavaSEPort
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors
1 warning
/home/pathTo/myProject/nbproject/build-impl.xml:914: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/pathTo/myProject/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1445: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/nbproject/build-impl.xml:937: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/pathTo/CodenameOneSRC/CodenameOne/Ports/JavaSE/nbproject/build-impl.xml:269: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 14 seconds)
```

Furthermore the project cannot be run anymore because the main class is not found (although I added the ports/JavaSE.jar in the run section).

What can I do to correctly attach sources and make change to CN1 source code ?

Any help appreciated,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need the cn1-binaries project and need to make sure the paths within the JavaSE project lead to valid locations within that project.

E.g. `GaussianFilter` is defined within `Filters.jar` that resides in that project.